# How do I build Libgdx.so from source for Android with gdb tracing enabled?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, libgdx, native

I have setup a debug ROM on an Android device, and enabled the DDMS Native Heap in search for a libgdx memory leak.

I now have a trace, but no source code attached to follow the lead.

I downloaded libgdx source code.

How do I build it enabling gdb tracing so I can follow the code referenced by the trace ?

Update:

I built the debug .so libgdx from source 
To do this, I modified the file:
libgdx/gdx/jni/build-android32.xml

Adding  to the compile-natives target
I also added APP_OPTIM := debug to the Application.mk in the same folder
And added '-g' to the Android.mk file in the same folder:
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:%=-I%) -O2 -Wall -D__ANDROID__

This, indeed, produces a dbg libgdx.so dynamic library place in 
libgdx/gdx/libs/armeabi

Although I am getting closer, I still cannot get the name of the function that is loading memory.

I am using arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line and the Hex address of the function, but it prints
??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the Android Source and build it.

Point DDMS to the libs with debug symbols.  On the command line:

export ANDROID_SYMBOLS=$ANDROID_SOURCE/out/target/product/flo/symbols/system/lib

Note that $ANDROID_SOURCE refers to the location where you built the Android source.

start DDMS from that shell

$ddms

Now you should see the native traces on ddms.

I also built libgdx from source and added $LIBGDX_SOURCE/libgdx/gdx/obj/local/armeabi/libgdx.so
to $ANDROID_SOURCE/out/target/product/flo/symbols/system/lib to see the method names for libgdx.so.

Preliminaries

You need to set the device to debug memory

```
adb root
adb shell setprop libc.debug.malloc 1
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

The device must be rooted or with a dbg ROM.